# Block traffic from specific ISPs/Botnetworks?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, traffic

I am getting a lot of traffic from cloud server providers / bots,

how can I completely block this ISPs?

With a .htaccess?

[image]

Comment: might be better suited for server fault

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`Deny`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#deny) directive. For example, `Deny from 10.1.2.0/24`.